# form validation inside a bootstrap wizard

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I was watching a lot of example but none of them worked at all for me.
I have a form inside a wizard and I am using Bootstrap for my whole site, I saw and tried several examples but I had no luck.
I hope someone can help to find what im doing wrong, ty in advance

So here's my html:

```
<div class="input_align">
    <label class="control-label4" for="facility_name">Facility Name</label>

    <input type="text" class="input-largex3" name="facility_name" id="" required >
</div>

<div class="multi_align">
    <div class="input_align input_col1">
        <label class="control-label4" for="facility_npi">Facility NPI</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="" name="facility_npi">
    </div>
    <div class="input_align input_col2">
        <label class="control-label2" for="fed_id">Fed ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="" name="fed_id">
    </div>
    <div class="input_align input_col2">
        <label class="control-label2" for="medicare_id">Med ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="" name="med_id">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Js

```
$('#new-contract').validate({
        rules: {
          facility_name: {
            required: true,
          },
          facility_npi: {
            required: true,
          },
          fed_id: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
          }
        },

        highlight: function(label) {
            $(label).closest('input').removeClass ('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label
                .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('input').addClass('success');
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         error.appendTo( element.parents ('input') );
       }
      });
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I dont get any validation at all, any signal of errors, anything...it is really frustrating when u dont even get errors

Answer (score 0):

**1)**  Your `input` elements **must** be contained within the `<form></form>` tags.  The jQuery Validate plugin will not work otherwise.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/uL2Y8/**

**2)**  Perhaps you forgot to include jQuery and/or jQuery Validate plugin.  Look at the left panel of the jsFiddle under "Frameworks" and "External Resources".  Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

You should have two lines, in this order, where the `src` contains the correct URL to the location where you've placed those files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

**3)**  You have all kinds of little mistakes.  Some invalid HTML (unclosed `input` elements) and you've declared some rules twice.  If you've already declared `required` within your `.validate({})` options/rules, then you do **not** also need it inside here:

```
<input type="text" name="facility_name" required>
```

**4)**  Maybe you don't need to over-ride the plugin's default `highlight`, `success`, and `errorPlacement` callback functions.  When using your custom callback functions for these, you lose the error messages.

http://jsfiddle.net/uL2Y8/1/

Answer (score -1):

Please wrap your form like below :
check Jsfiddle [check the form](http://jsfiddle.net/GeQ8G/1)

```
<div id="new-contract">
<div class="input_align">
    <label class="control-label4" for="facility_name">Facility Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-largex3" name="facility_name"
    id="" required>
</div>
<div class="multi_align">
    <div class="input_align input_col1">
        <label class="control-label4" for="facility_npi">Facility NPI</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="" name="facility_npi">
    </div>
    <div class="input_align input_col2">
        <label class="control-label2" for="fed_id">Fed ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="" name="fed_id">
    </div>
    <div class="input_align input_col2">
        <label class="control-label2" for="medicare_id">Med ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="" name="med_id">
    </div>
</div>
```